# When testing an Angular app, how can I get Jest to recognize CanvasJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, canvasjs

I am using [CanvasJS](https://canvasjs.com/) to display charts in an Angular app. The charts display properly when running my app, so I know CanvasJS is a part of the project and is working. However, Jest can't find CanvasJS when unit testing, here's the error:

```
import Charts from '../core/charts';
       ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

  1 | import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
> 2 | import * as CanvasJS from 'canvasjs';
    | ^
  3 |
```

What could be causing this, and what is the workaround?